# onRender method for Bootstrap Datepicker not working properly on selection of months and year directly

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this [Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) in my application. In this "onRender" method is available for disable dates. This is working when i click date, but when i change month directly click on month or year then the disable is not working.

I am using same code as in the link for check-in and checkout condition.

This issue already present on example code, so how can i disabled the previous months also or year.